# Going from Hongik Univ to Incheon intairport by train: possible with T-money card?

Tags: trains, public-transport, airport-transfer, south-korea, seoul

T-money is an all-around transportation card used for public buses, subways, taxis, and convenience stores that accept T-money as a form of transaction (most do). The function of a T-money card is like a debit card, where money is deposited into the card and used to get around the city of Seoul and the Gyeonggi-do district.  Can I use my T-money card for the all stop train to the airport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [Korean Tourism Organisation](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_2_1.jsp)

> Transportation card purchase locations: Transportation Center on B1F of Incheon Int’l Airport Terminal 1 & Terminal 2 (Single-journey transit card), **convenience stores inside Incheon International Airport (Tmoney card)**, Tourist Information Center near Gates 5 & 10 on 1F of Incheon International Airport Terminal 1 (MPASS)

That's advice for arriving passengers. They also list it here:

> Transportation card information: **Tmoney** / Exclusive Tourist Cards

Answer (score 1):

In 2017, I was visiting South Korea, flew into Incheon airport, got a T-Money card there and used it all the way from there on the all-stops train into the city centre where my hotel was without issue.

This should not have changed.